# Using count in oracle sql developer

Tags: sql, database, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using oracle sql developer and I can't get this query to function. It's telling me its not a single group function. Please help.

```
SELECT LGBRAND.BRAND_NAME, LGPRODUCT.PROD_DESCRIPT,
    COUNT (LGPRODUCT.PROD_DESCRIPT) AS "NUMPRODUCTS"
FROM LGBRAND, LGPRODUCT
ORDER BY LGBRAND.BRAND_NAME;
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to get the total different products grouped by each brand name.

Comment: It's helpful to specify what database you are using.  Oracle SQL Developer works with many different databases.  We can guess that you are using Oracle but that may be an incorrect guess.  You are doing a Cartesian join between the two tables.  That seems highly unlikely to be what you want-- is there really no column that relates the `lgbrand` and `lgproduct` tables?  You'll need the `GROUP BY` as well, as discussed below, of course, but you'll probably get the wrong answer without the join logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when using aggregate functions you need to use `group by` clause

All aggregate functions like avg, count,sum needs to be used along with a group by function. If you dont use a group by clause, you are performing the function on all the rows of the table.

```
  SELECT LGBRAND.BRAND_NAME,
           LGPRODUCT.PROD_DESCRIPT,
           COUNT (LGPRODUCT.PROD_DESCRIPT) AS "NUMPRODUCTS"
    FROM LGBRAND, LGPRODUCT,
    GROUP BY LGBRAND.BRAND;
```

Comment: when i go to run the query it is telling me I have an invalid table name, any ideas?

Comment: you need to join the two tables like `SELECT LGBRAND.BRAND_NAME,
           LGPRODUCT.PROD_DESCRIPT,
           COUNT (LGPRODUCT.PROD_DESCRIPT) AS "NUMPRODUCTS"
    FROM LGBRAND join LGPRODUCT on LGBRAND.id=LGPRODUCT.id
    GROUP BY LGBRAND.BRAND_NAME;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `GROUP BY` clause.